# Generate structure classes from StructureDefintion with HAPI

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

Is it possible to generate structure classes from a custom StructureDefintion in a similar fashion as HAPI generates official DSTU2/3 structure classes?

I want to implement some local StructureDefinition from simplifier.net (For example: https://simplifier.net/NictizSTU3/nl-core-address/).

The documentation of HAPI wasn't helping me either, am i suppose to use the hapi-tinder-plugin?

It seems tedious and error prone to hand write custom structures as specified in http://hapifhir.io/doc_custom_structures.html

For me the ideal workflow is something like:

- Fetch StructureDefinition from simplifier
- Generate models for the StructureDefinition
- Register generated models in HAPI and fill the models accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating classes from profiles is on our list of things to do, but doing it well (particularly when there's slicing involved) isn't super-easy, so most of the reference implementations have been holding off until there's funding support to get it done.